# Bootstrap collapse initially show/hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-cli

I am practicing Bootstrap 3 on an Angular app.

For some buttons, I want them to hide themselves when open the webpage on the mobile, and show them when open webpage on a laptop.

As far as I know, the class `navbar-collapse` does help to do the work, but it also contains other formatting styles that will change my button look, which I don't like. I know using `!important` to override could work but I don't think it is a proper way.

Also, from Bootstrap instructions I know that

> `collapse`  hides content
>
> `collapse in`  shows content

But still, it can only set one of the 2 original status.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Can I set the show/hide the collapse buttons according to window width?
2. Can I do it without a lot of CSS change in `@Media ..`
3. Shall I use ngClass? Can I get window width using Angular?

Thanks!!

---

My simplified codes  here:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".moreOptions" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <strong><u> Show Options </u></strong>
   </button>
</div>
<div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default collapse in moreOptions" (click)="doSomething()">
             DoSomething
   </button>
</div>
```

*: I am using .moreOptions not #moreOptions because I have multiple options in different parts of the webpage.

---

I tried it by continue using `navbar-collapse`, while I add the full `.btn` to my css file to override the related styles.

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #ccc !important;
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

This does not work as these `!important` parameters need to change when collapse.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ This is for bootstrap for but bootstrap 3 has also this kind of classes

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see why your attempt is not working? For what I read, `@media` queries are the way to go, you don't need Angular for that. And if you do, yes, getting the window width is no big deal with `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: You can do it with pure css, adding the classes from here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities ex.   <button class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm visible-lg">Click</button> for hide in small device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, at last I made it by continue using `navbar-collapse`, while I added a part of `.btn` to my css file to override the related styles.

```
.btn {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #ccc !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If there are other methods, please don't hesitate to post them here.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using bootstrap css' classes, they help with this kind of issues.

You have classes such as `hidden-xs` or `visible-xs` that will help you.

Check the [Bootstrap documentation about this matter](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Comment: Though it does not work with Bootstrap `collapse` button, this is a good answer.